# For loop with changing range

Tags: python, loops

I got a little question: I got 2 lists with equal lengths.

As you can see below in my code, if appropriate circumstances take place, I delete some of the elements from the list. I have to do my work very carefully so my question is - does the for loop check by every iteration if len(whole_st_gen) is changing ?? Won't it skip some items??

```
whole_st_gen = []
whole_end_gen = [] // the length of both of them is 38273
if_merge = 0
here_merge = 0
deleting = False

for x in range (0, len(whole_st_gen)):
    if_merge = x
    if x == len(whole_st_gen)-1:
        break
    for y in range (x+1, len(whole_st_gen)):
        if whole_end_gen[x]>whole_end_gen[y]:
            deleting = True
            here_merge = y
            continue
        else:
            break
    if deleting == True:
        deleting = False
        del whole_st_gen[x:here_merge]
        del whole_end_gen[x:here_merge]
    if_merge = 0
    here_merge = 0

print len(whole_st_gen) # here's length is 1852, so i think it could work properly, just want to be sure!
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Just use a while loop: `i = 0`; `while i < len(my_list): ...`; if an element was deleted, then don't increment `i`, otherwise do increment `i`.

Comment: Your code needs some cleaning up. Give me a minute..

Comment: No, a for loop wont recognise that the list has been modified. Check out the answer here: [strange result when removing item from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, related for sure, but there's also the implied question of, "How do I make _this_ work?".

Comment: Thanks! Okay mabye I'll use while, but i want to check @Cyphase solution :)

Comment: @theCember, what is the code supposed to be doing? Do you know whether your current code works?

Comment: @theCember, I don't understand; what is your code supposed to do?

Comment: @Cyphase
Look i have lists _st_gen , end_gen  they are the ranges , at for example:
whole_st_gen [10] #here for example 600
whole_end_gen[10] #here 700 , this pair make range next is _st+_end at [11]
It gives me the distance where i need to put some values in other stuff in this range, the problem is, at  position for example [9] st==550 and end==100
So I delete position 10 because, range pair at [9] covers this at [10]
Clear enough?

Comment: You delete pair 10 because it's covered by pair 9? But it's not; and in fact, pair 9 is starting at a higher number than it ends at. Please try to elaborate.

Comment: Here are the real last 4 pairs from my project (i zipped two of the lists, sort them by _st , ascending)
          _ST           _END
a)248872850 248919146
b)248873855 248873960
c)248874248 248874319
d)248931413 248937105

As you see a) have the least _st and this range covers b,c,d, thats why I  delete b,c,d cause this range is only need to.
So I think my way of solving this is right :)

Comment: It doesn't cover `d`, just so you know. So you want to delete all ranges that are completely included in another range, right?

Comment: Yes exactly want to delete ranges which are in other bigger ranges :)

Comment: @theCember, what about, e.g. `(1, 5)`, `(6, 10)`, `(10, 15)`, `(13, 17)`? Mention me so I'll see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , when you are using `range()` method, it does not check the length of the array in each iteration. Especially in Python 2.x , `range()` returns a list , which is what you iterate over, and this list is created at the start of the loop , it does not get recalculated in each iteration. So there can be multiple issues you can run into when using above method.

One being that you can skip some elements, since if you delete an element from the list, the indices of the list are rearranged to make a contigous sequence, so you would end up missing some elements.

Secondly, you can end up getitng `IndexError` , Simple example of that -

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in range(0,len(l)):
...     del l[i]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

This is because like I said in starting range() computes the complete range (even `xrange()` in Python 2.x) at the start itself. This does not happen for you because of -

```
if x == len(whole_st_gen)-1:
    break
```

Like said in the comments an easier way for you to go would be to use `while` loop , which does not increment when deleting the item. Example -

```
if_merge = 0
here_merge = 0
deleting = False
x = 0
while x < len(whole_st_gen):
    for y in range (x+1, len(whole_st_gen)):
        if whole_end_gen[x]>whole_end_gen[y]:
            deleting = True
            here_merge = y
        else:
            break
    if deleting == True:
        deleting = False
        del whole_st_gen[x:here_merge]
        del whole_end_gen[x:here_merge]
    else:
        x += 1
    here_merge = 0

print len(whole_st_gen)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I will check that in a moment! :)

Comment: This code looks better, but my previous version with for gave me same results :)

Comment: Yes, but your for loop can miss some elements, like i said above in explanation , first point

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` statement the expression list (after the `in`) is evaluated first to get an iterator (or iterable) which is then used for the iteration, the expression list is not evaluated again in each iteration.

In your case you call the `range` function to retrieve an iterator (in python3) or iterable (in python2 in the form of a list). In both cases the iterator/iterable will yield `len(whole_st_gen)` (as it evaluates when you reach the `for` statement from above) numbers (ranging from zero). If you alter the `whole_st_len` in the loop it will not affect the iterator and it will yield the same numbers anyway (leading to you skipping numbers, and eventually get numbers that are beyond the indices for `whole_st_gen`).

As opposed to the situation where you iterate over the container itself the behaviour when you do this is fully specified. You may delete and insert elements in the container if you are careful.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a straight answer to your question, you should not delete items on a list while iterating on the same list, it yields unexpected results to you as some items will be skipped. Inorder to avoid this you can use copy of same list in the iteration.

Comment: While your point is true, this makes more sense as a comment than an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @bitoiu, Have you read the question?, I am sure this answers his question It may require some more explanation though

Comment: @pydev, I guess the 3 upvotes to the first comment confirm my comment.

Comment: @bitoiu, the first comment does not say " This does not provide an answer to the question". It says " this makes more sense as a comment than an answer "